# capture radio value and append to the querystring URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, radio-button, query-string

I have this code where there are a couple of radiobuttones and an inputbox. I have captured inputbox value and added to the URL as a qurystring onclick of a button. But i also need to capture the value of selected radio and also pass it as querystring to the url. It should look like: http://mysite.com/events/SitePages/test1.aspx?kwd=InputBoxvalue&type=RadioValue

How do I do this?

```
All<input name="EventRadio" type="radio" value="All"/>
Events<input name="EventRadio" type="radio" value="Events"/>
Classes<input name="EventRadio" type="radio" value="Classes"/>
<input name="keyword" type="text" id="EventSearchBox"/>
<input name="SearchButton" type="button" value="Search"
     onClick="location.href='http://mysite.com/events/SitePages/test1.aspx?kwd='+ document.getElementById('EventSearchBox').value; return false;"/><br/><br/>
```

Comment: Is the jQuery tag really needed?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="SearchButton" type="button" value="Search"/>
```

instead of adding the `onClick` property attach a click event handler like

```
$("input[name='SearchButton']").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var radioVal = $(":radio:selected").val();
location.href='http://mysite.com/events/SitePages/test1.aspx?kwd='+ document.getElementById('EventSearchBox').value+"&radioVal="+radioVal
});
```